# Attendance system with Radio buttons

Tags: php, radio-button

First of all I want to thank you in advance for your spending time to help me.
I am making attendance form to my school with multiple radio buttons. Students and 
their classes are in a database and when a teacher chose class , let say class 7 
then all students name of class 7 populate as a list in a table. And beside every student's name there will be three radio buttons to chose. Those's value will be  Accepted , Not accepted , and Tardy.
To poplate students I use Java function as below:(found in W3school) the first page. 
Let say populate.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showUser(str)
{
if (str=="")
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
return;
} 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a class:</option>
<?php
getClasses();

?>
</select>
</form>
<br />

</body>
</html> 
<?php
```

// And the second page will be offcourse users.php and is as below:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];


$sql = "SELECT s.firstname, s.lastname, s.student_id, s.class_id, cl.class_id ". 
" FROM students s ". 
" INNER JOIN classes cl ON cl.class_id = s.class_id ".
" WHERE s.class_id =$q "; 


$result = mysql_query($sql);

print '<table border="2">'.
'<tr>'.
'<th>Firstname</th>'.
'<th>Lastname</th>'.
'<th>Kind of absence</th>'.

'</tr>';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

print  '<tr>'.
'<td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td>'.
'<td>'. $row['lastname'] . '</td>'.
'<td>'.
'<form method="post" action="getuser.php">'. 
'<input type="radio" name="attendance[]"        
value="1">Accepted</input>'. 
'<input type="radio" name="attendance[]" value="2"> Not  
accepted</input>'.
'<input type="radio" name="attendance[]" value="3"> Tardy</input>'.

'</form>'. 

'</td>'.

'</tr>';

}

print '<tr>'.
'<td>'.
'<form method="post" action="getuser.php">'. 
'<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send"> &nbsp'.
'</form>'. 
'</td>'.
```

// I don't know where to put the submit button form.

```
print '</table>';
```

//What I'am trying is to get all values of radio buttons and insert them in database.

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['submit']) && $_REQUEST['submit'] != "") {
if(isset($_POST['attendance']))
{

$atendance = $_POST['attendance'];

for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($attendance);$i++) {
```

// I don't how but I know I have to collect student_id's too in array maybe here

```
$sql2 = " INSERT INTO absence (student_id, attendans_id  ) ".
" VALUES (".$student_id.", '".$attendance[$i]."') ";
mysql_query($sql2) or die(mysql_error());

}    

}

}
```

//So dear PHP lovers... I know I doing totaly wrong but I don't know how to fix this
problem and I would be greatful if you can help me. Thank you again in advance. There will be three radio buttons to chose för every student. I mean Beside every name there will be three alternativ to chose.... three radio buttons for every student with value accepted, not accepted and Tardy.

?>

Comment: Edit your question to be formatted correctly I have no idea what's going on here

Answer (score -1):

html code

```
<form action="getStudents.php" method="POST >
<input type="radio" name="class" value="7" />Class 7</input>
<input type="radio" name="class" value="8" />Class 8</input>
<input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
</form>
```

PHP code

```
$class = $_POST['class'];
sql query = "select * from class where class.number={$class}";
<table >
<thead><th>First Name</th><th>Middle name</th><th>Last name</th></thead>
<tbody>
foreach ($query as $x)
{

 <tr><td>$x->firstnamel</td><td>$x->middlename</td><td>$x->lastname</td></tr>


}
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this is not an answer, use comments for that

Comment: Thank you giorgio for your help, But I don't think I was clearly telling my problem. I get student names from Database when I chose class, no problem with that. Their name populate in a table. Then I want three radio buttons beside every student name. I mean three alternativ to chose for every student. The alternative is Accepted, Not accepted and Tardy. So when I put your html code I get submit button for every student too. I want one submit button for all but three radio for everybody. Then I want to insert those value of buttons and student id's to database.

Comment: Soroush Atarod: I don't understand what you mean. What do you mean post design mockup?

Comment: My problem is now solved. Thank you very much for your help guys. You are wonderful people. Thank you now I will have a nice weekend. My form and getting value of radio buttons was totaly wrong. God bless you!